# ZedGraph labels

Tags: asp.net, controls, charts, zedgraph

In ZedGraph, how do I show text labels for each point and in the `XAxis` all together?

If I do

```
myPane.XAxis.Type = AxisType.Text;
myPane.XAxis.Scale.TextLabels = array_of_string;
```

I get labels on the XAxis like this

[image]

And if I do

```
for (int i = 0; i < myCurve.Points.Count; i++)
{
    PointPair pt = myCurve.Points[i];
    // Create a text label from the Y data value
    TextObj text = new TextObj(
        pt.Y.ToString("f0"), pt.X, pt.Y + 0.1,
        CoordType.AxisXYScale, AlignH.Left, AlignV.Center);
    text.ZOrder = ZOrder.A_InFront;
    text.FontSpec.Angle = 0;
    myPane.GraphObjList.Add(text);
}
```

I get labels on the curve, like this

[image: Alt text, Pointlabel.png]

But if I do both at the same time, labels on the curve disappear.

Is there a way to combine both kind of labels?

Comment: I've updated my answer according to your clarifications

Comment: eKek0, is the new second image sufficiently correct?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I've changed my answer after you clarified the question.
You just have to remember to position the labels correctly:

```
<%
  System.Collections.Generic.List<ZedGraphWebPointPair> points = new System.Collections.Generic.List<ZedGraphWebPointPair>();
  for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++)
  {
    // Let's have some fun with maths
    points.Add(new ZedGraphWebPointPair
    {
      X = i,
      Y = Math.Pow(i - 10, 2) * -1 + 120
    });
  }

  System.Collections.Generic.List<string> XAxisLabels = new System.Collections.Generic.List<string>();

  TestGraph.CurveList.Add(new ZedGraphWebLineItem { Color = System.Drawing.Color.Red });
  TestGraph.XAxis.Scale.FontSpec.Size = 9;

  int j = 1;
  foreach (ZedGraphWebPointPair point in points)
  {
    // Add the points we calculated
    TestGraph.CurveList[0].Points.Add(point);

    // Add the labels for the points
    TestGraph.GraphObjList.Add(new ZedGraphWebTextObj
    {
      Location =
      {
        CoordinateFrame = ZedGraph.CoordType.XChartFractionYScale,
        // Make sure we position them according to the CoordinateFrame
        X = Convert.ToSingle(j) / points.Count - 0.05f,
        Y = Convert.ToSingle(point.Y) + 3f,
        AlignV = ZedGraph.AlignV.Top
      },
      Text = point.Y.ToString(),
      FontSpec = { Angle = 90, Size = 9, Border = { IsVisible = false } }
    });

    // Add the labels for the XAxis
    XAxisLabels.Add(String.Format("P{0}", j));

    j++;
  }

  TestGraph.RenderGraph += delegate(ZedGraphWeb zgw, System.Drawing.Graphics g, ZedGraph.MasterPane mp)
  {
    ZedGraph.GraphPane gp = mp[0];
    gp.XAxis.Type = ZedGraph.AxisType.Text;
    gp.XAxis.Scale.TextLabels = XAxisLabels.ToArray();
  };

%>
```

That code will produce this graph:

[image: ZedGraph sample]

Answer (score 0):

If the axis type is text, the code below is easier to get x-coordinates of the points ;)

```
for (int tPoint = 0; tPoint < curve.Points.Count; tPoint++)
{
    TextObj text = new TextObj(curve.Points[tPoint].Y.ToString(), curve.Points[tPoint].X, curve.Points[tPoint].Y + 10);
}
```