# Zedgraph - determine length of tic on an axis?

Tags: .net, graph, zedgraph

In [Zedgraph](http://zedgraph.org/wiki/index.php?title=Main_Page) building a line chart. I have some requirements for axes labels which can't be produced automatically so inspired by this [other Stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/907111/zedgraph-net-having-axis-labels-for-actual-values-only) I'm building a custom axis.

I can draw the Axis OK and I can place the labels but I want to draw my own tics. To do this I'd like to know the colour/pen width/size etc of the tics on the other axes.

Determining the [colour and pen width are no problem](http://zedgraph.sourceforge.net/documentation/html/T_ZedGraph_MajorTic.htm) but finding out the length of a tic is difficult (I mean how long is it drawn away from the axis).

I'm using a [LineObj](http://zedgraph.sourceforge.net/documentation/html/T_ZedGraph_LineObj.htm) to draw the custom tics but I can't figure out how to long to draw them to match other non-custom tics .

Does anyone know where this is defined (or have a smarter way of drawing your own tics than using LineObjs ?)

Comment: I don't really get what you are trying to do? A fake tic with a custom size/width, at some specified place, right? Maybe you will submit some fast drawing for better understanding?

Answer (score 0):

You said:

> Determining the colour and pen width
> are no problem but finding out the
> length of a tic is difficult (I mean
> how long is it drawn away from the
> axis).

but there are two properties of the `MajorTic` you can use. From the documentation:

> Size -    The length of the major tic
> marks.
>
> PenWidth - Gets or sets the pen
> width to be used when drawing the tic
> marks for this Axis

So where's the problem?