# How to add a text on top of a column with ZedGraph?

Tags: zedgraph

How can I add some text on top of a bar in a chart.
This is the code I have to add the bar:

```
var color = ColorTranslator.FromHtml(row.Colour);
var barItem = graphPane.AddBar(row.Propensity.ToString(), null, Ys.ToArray(), color);
```

Thank you

Comment: See related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/816256/161052 which might be of help.

Answer (score 6):

Here is a quick example using `TextObj` to simply add labels to each bar.

```
GraphPane myPane = zedGraphControl1.GraphPane;

double[] y = { 100, 50, 75, 125 };

BarItem myBar = myPane.AddBar("Data", null, y, Color.Red);
for (int i = 0; i < myBar.Points.Count; i++)
{
    TextObj barLabel = new TextObj(myBar.Points[i].Y.ToString(), myBar.Points[i].X, myBar.Points[i].Y + 5);
    barLabel.FontSpec.Border.IsVisible = false;
    myPane.GraphObjList.Add(barLabel);
}

myBar.Label.IsVisible = true;

zedGraphControl1.AxisChange();
zedGraphControl1.Invalidate();
```

[image: Bar chart with labels]

Of course this just uses the value of the data as the label. If you wanted to use custom labels, you could create a string array or list and use that inside the loop.

Here are some ZedGraph references:

- Introduction and examples: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/graphics/zedgraph.aspx
- Source code documentation: http://zedgraph.sourceforge.net/documentation/default.html

Answer (score 1):

You need to define AlignH and AlignV in your text object:

```
TextObj textLabel = new TextObj(value.ToString(), positionX, value, CoordType.AxisXYScale, AlignH.Center, AlignV.Top);
```

AlignV define the position of your value on the bar.

Answer (score 0):

Providing you want the label text to match the value of each bar, then you can do it with a single line of code:

```
BarItem.CreateBarLabels(graphPane, false, "F0");
```

Note that the 3rd parameter is a `double.ToString` format. e.g. `"F0" = 12`, `"F2" = 12.34`

However, if you want any flexibity with it then this solution is not ideal. It also doesn't work very well if you have a stacked bar chart, because having any `0` value data will cause labels to overlap and look horrific